# Running node (Express) server and dist folder / adding js folder

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, frontend, backend

I have created server using nodeJS where I adding dist folder created by webpack.

server.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")))
```

There is js folder also including all js files.

How can I add also js folder in correct way in server file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the js folder inside of `dist`? if so... you don't need to do anything. Else, do the same t hing you did for `dist`.

Comment: js folder is outside of dist folder, thats why I'm asking how can I add js folder.

Comment: yeah, so just repeat what you did for dist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

__dirname will return a relative path for your nodejs project.
 You can print path.join(__dirname, "dist") in console and make sure that this folder is exists.